# React Native and Nested navigation, the good way?

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-native-navigation

After some days, I'm asking here because I didn't find a proper solution on the web.

My App.js render() return drawer navigator as you see :

```js
render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator
                    drawerContent={(props) => <this.customDrawerContent {...props} />}
                    initialRouteName="Past Launches"
                >
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={drawerOptions}/>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Next Launch" component={NextLaunch} options={drawerOptions}/>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Past Launches" component={this.pastLaunches} options={drawerOptions}/>
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
}
```

And here you can see my stack navigator returned by pastLaunches function :

```js
pastLaunches() {
   return (
     <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="launches" component={Launches} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="details" component={PastLaunchDetails} options={drawerOptions}/>
     </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Here, the result :

[image]

But when I open past launch details :

[image]

We can see the drawer header AND the stack header.

**My question : How to hide the drawer header when I'm on this view ?**

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Finally use headerShown: false

```
const drawerOptions = { headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#181C1F"}, headerTintColor: "white" };



export default class App extends React.Component {
    pastLaunches() {
        return (
          <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
            <Stack.Screen name="launches" component={Launches} />
            <Stack.Screen name="details" component={PastLaunchDetails} options={drawerOptions}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        );
    }

    customDrawerContent(props) {
        return (
            <ImageBackground style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)', flex: 1}} >
                    <DrawerItemList {...props} labelStyle={{ color: "white" }} activeTintColor="black" itemStyle={{ flex: 1 }}/>
                </DrawerContentScrollView>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator
                    drawerContent={(props) => <this.customDrawerContent {...props} />}
                    initialRouteName="Past Launches"
                    headerMode='none'
                >
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{...drawerOptions, headerShown: false}}/>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Next Launch" component={NextLaunch} options={{...drawerOptions, headerShown: false}}/>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Past Launches" component={this.pastLaunches} options={{...drawerOptions, headerShown: false}}/>
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

Custom Drawer header

```
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'

export const CustomDrawerHeader = (props) => {
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      return (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingVertical: 12, paddingHorizontal: 12}}>
         <Button onPress={() => {
           navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
         }}
         title='Menu icon'></Button>
         <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>)
}
```

Custom back Header

```
export const CustomStackHeader = (props) => {
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      return (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingVertical: 12, paddingHorizontal: 12}}>
         <Button onPress={() => {
           navigation.goBack();
         }}
         title='Back icon'></Button>
         <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>)
}
```

Also I don't recomend to keep your stackNavigator in a method inside your drawer component move it outside(you will get re-renders and you will lose performance).

Comment: I tried but your idea hide "Past Launches" from drawer navigation and not the header when I'm on past launch details.
I understand your second comments, my stack navigator should be in Past Launches component ?

Comment: fork this snack and make a repro of your issue and include where you put past launches and I can help you in a better way. fork this snack https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/41a9b3

Comment: You can see the code in action here : https://snack.expo.io/@yannickslc/react-nav

Comment: I update the answer sorry can't login in expo to share a new one

Comment: I saw your answer but you hide the header drawer, now you cannot navigate between the different views. Also, how the user can be know to change page ? Thank again !

Comment: You ask for hide drawer header, thinking in design it should the way only show the back button and the tittle of the current header, if you want to keep header navigation icon and navigate between pages you should make a custom header component. what u mean with user can be know to change page

Comment: If you look the previous screenshots in the main post, the first still like that. On the second screenshot, only the header with hamburger icon (drawer header) should be hide.
So, your idea is to create a custom header for my navigation ? Yes, I could try. But can I use event navigation to see a boolean variable to toggle headerShown option ?

Basically :

````javasscript
let hideHeader = 'details' == route;
// Then i do :
// options={{...drawerOptions, headerShown: hideHeader}}
````

But my experience with reactnative is really short, I don't know I can do that

Comment: you have actions to make that work. I make an update to the snack, the best is to make custom headers for drawer and for back headers. here is the snack https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/react-nav